# UIImage size doubled when converted to CGImage?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, cgimage

I am trying to crop part of an image taken with the iPhone's camera via the `cropping(to:)` method on a `CGImage` but I am encountering a weird phenomenon where my `UIImage`'s dimensions are doubled when converted with `.cgImage` which, obviously, prevents me from doing what I want.

The flow is:

1. Picture is taken with the camera and goes into a full-screen imageContainerView
2. A "screenshot" of this imageContainerView is made with a UIView extension, effectively resizing the image to the container's dimensions
3. imageContainerView's `.image` is set to now be the "screenshot"

---

```
let croppedImage = imageContainerView.renderToImage()
imageContainerView.image = croppedImage
print(imageContainerView.image!.size) //yields (320.0, 568.0)
print(imageContainerView.image!.cgImage!.width, imageContainerView.image!.cgImage!.height) //yields (640, 1136) ??

extension UIView {

    func renderToImage(afterScreenUpdates: Bool = false) -> UIImage {

        let rendererFormat = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default()
        rendererFormat.opaque = isOpaque
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: bounds.size, format: rendererFormat)

        let snapshotImage = renderer.image { _ in
            drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: afterScreenUpdates)
        }
        return snapshotImage
    }
}
```

I have been wandering around here with no success so far and would gladly appreciate a pointer or a suggestion on how/why the image size is suddenly doubled.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a thought because I don't know for sure.... but why would some sort of rendering - in your case to a `imageViewContainer` - result in "effectively resizing the image"? Sure, it may *scale* down to what you want for rendering. But resize a `UIImage.size`? That doesn't quite make sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `print(imageContainerView.image!.size)` prints the size of the image object in points and `print(imageContainerView.image!.cgImage!.width, imageContainerView.image!.cgImage!.height)` print the size of the actual image in pixels.

On iPhone you are using there are 2 pixels for evert point in both horizontal and vertical.  The UIImage scale property will give you the factor which in your case will be 2.

See this link [iPhone Resolutions](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions)